# how to validate datatype in jolt transformation

Tags: jolt

I'm new to jolt transformation. I was wondering if there is a way to do a validation on data type then proceed.

I'm processing a json to insert record into hbase. From source I'm getting timestamp repeated for the same resource id which I want to use for row key.
So I just retrieve the first timestamp and concate with resource id to create row key. But I have an issue when there is only one timestamp in the record i.e when its not a list. Appreciate if someone can help me how to handle this situation.

input data

```
 {  "resource": {
    "id": "200629068",
    "name": "resource_name_1)",
    "parent": {
      "id": 200053744,
      "name": "parent_name"
    },
    "properties": {
      "AP_ifSpeed": "0",
      "DisplaySpeed": "0 (NotApplicable)",
      "description": "description"
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "id": "2215",
        "name": "metric_name 1"
      },
      "timestamp": 1535064595000,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "metric": {
        "id": "2216",
        "name": "metric_name_2"
      },
      "timestamp": 1535064595000,
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt transformation

```
  [{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "resource": {
        // "id": "resource_&",
        "name": "resource_&",
        "id": "resource_&",
        "parent": {
          "id": "parent_&",
          "name": "parent_&"
        },
        "properties": {
          "*": "&"
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "metric": {
            "id": {
              "*": {
                "@(3,value)": "&1"
              }
            },
            "name": {
              "*": {
                "@(3,value)": "&1"
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp": "timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp": {
        // get first element from list
        "0": "&1"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "rowkey": "=concat(@(1,resource_id),'_',@(1,timestamp))"
    }
    }
]
```

Output I'm getting

```
    { "resource_name" : "resource_name_1)",
  "resource_id" : "200629068",
  "parent_id" : 200053744,
  "parent_name" : "parent_name",
  "AP_ifSpeed" : "0",
  "DisplaySpeed" : "0 (NotApplicable)",
  "description" : "description",
  "2215" : 0,
  "metric_name 1" : 0,
  "timestamp" : 1535064595000,
  "2216" : 1,
  "metric_name_2" : 1,
  "rowkey" : "200629068_1535064595000"
}
```

when there is only one timestamp then I get 
 "rowkey" : "200629068_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your shift make the output "timestamp" always be an array, even if the incoming data array only has one element in it.

```
 "timestamp": "timestamp[]"
```